# Develop Windows based application with 1/10th milisecond precision

Tags: windows, estimation, real-time

I want to develop a Windows based application that would interface with external hardware using serial communication. The hardware would in turn relay back the feedback to the application. This entire loop should be ideally completed within a millisecond.

Is it possible to develop such an application on Windows OS? I read somewhere that only 0.01 seconds accurate precision can be achieved on Windows. Initially I have tried developing a smaller model running on Labview with a 2 line matlab script, but even that is taking atleast 2 ms to execute without any external communication.

I went through the [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1739259/how-to-use-queryperformancecounter) link which talks about microseconds timing in Windows in C++. Which gives me the idea that Windows is not accurate to even a millisecond precision. Do I have to leave Windows and develop an RTOS/bare metal application on a suitable hardware?

Comment: By the way, one of the mitigation for CPU branch prediction related vulnerabilities (spectre, meldown, etc...), is to report less precision in timers. The reason is that many of the exploit are based on accurate measures of time to identify what is is CPU cache, at least that is the gist of it. Because of that mitigation, you could have code that runs as fast as you need, and yet, when you measure it, it says it is slower.

Comment: Would taking an average over several runs mitigate this error. Or maybe putting the whole thing in a for loop and measure the time by dividing total time over iterations @Theraot

Comment: Right, if you measure the total time of a lot of iteration and divide by the number of iterations, the effect of the mitigation should be minimized, that is you will get a more accurate measurement. And, of course, the more iterations, the better.

Comment: What is the _reason_ you want such a fast realtime connection?  Is it really necessary?  On any OS you will have trouble with such timings, as the OS can (and will) give processor time to other applications during which your program will be doing nothing.

Comment: Windows has multimedia timers that will give you much better than the 20ms or precision that Windows normally has.

Comment: "`I went through the this link which talks about microseconds timing in Windows in C++. Which gives me the idea that Windows is not accurate to even a millisecond precision`." This doesn't make sense... microseconds are smaller than milliseconds. How do you conclude that "Windows is not accurate to even a millisecond"? It's the other way round. Also, do you care about **measuring** performance, or **achieving** it? They are two different things. You can usually find a more accurate way to **measure** performance, but you can't always **achieve** the desired performance.

Comment: @Turksarama that is my concern here actually. How do I ensure that the OS gives priority to my application and always allocates CPU time. I guess only a bare metal application can do that?

Comment: @VectorZita if you go through the first answer on that link. It mentions measuring the accuracy of sleep function using a queryperformancecounter. I tried that program on my system with a vast range of results for the same code while measuring in both ms and us. My goal is to measure hardware performance giving instructions at 1ms steps and then modifying those instructions based on the feedback by hardware. To prove my hardware I need it to achieve those instructions (or get close to it) within a ms. I hope this gives a better context

Comment: 1ms is actually a lot of time in computer terms.

Comment: And Matlab isn't the fastest thing in the world.

Comment: @RobertHarvey absolutely seconded.

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal If you want more information, you really have to describe what specifically (or _almost_ specifically) you want to do. It might well be possible that the hardware or the I/O ends up being the limiting factor.

Comment: @RobertHarvey agreed 1ms is a good amount of time. But how to realistically measure that time so I can be sure that my entire cycle executes within that time. Although Im sure that my hardware would run much faster than a ms yet there can be communication delays and hence the 1ms bottleneck measurement is crucial here

Comment: @VectorZita I just want to make sure that Windows is the right platform? If my one iteration executes within a ms, will Windows measure that accurately for me to be sure of my hardware? I am also depending on Windows for syncing 1ms time step across the entire set-up i.e. the Windows application should trigger an instruction every ms, which then initiates the loop iteration

Comment: "How do I ensure that the OS gives priority to my application and always allocates CPU time"? Set [realtime priority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663993/what-is-the-realtime-process-priority-setting-for).

Answer (score 4):

According to [this MSDN article section](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/acquiring-high-resolution-time-stamps#resolution-precision-accuracy-and-stability), Windows can definitely provide adequately accurate measurements for you to know whether your instructions are being executed fast enough, depending on the platform. As your measurements typically involve a total "counting" time-span of a few seconds.

Apart from that, the only way to find out if your processes can meet the requirement of < 1 ms cycle execution time, is to **profile** some actual code on the typical machine, where the code is expected to be used, along with the typical hardware you will be interfacing with.

As per your [comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/400994/develop-windows-based-application-with-1-10th-milisecond-precision?noredirect=1#comment882169_400994), Windows, as a platform, is not **entirely** relevant to your question. As you will see in the linked article, the whole "time measurement" concept really relies on the underlying hardware, for which Windows exposes suitably coded APIs to make it look like a high-precision clock.